# auto auto function template in DLang

Tags: syntax, d

From https://dlang.org/library/std/typecons/nullable.html:

```
auto auto nullable(T) (
  T t
);
```

What is this "double auto"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the Ddox documentation generator. You can use Ddoc: https://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons

Ddoc (DMD's built-in documentation generator) was there in the beginning and is the older system. Ddox was intended to be a replacement and thus both version are online, so that Ddox could be battle-tested. However, it still has a few issues which is why it hasn't replaced DMD's built-in documentation generator so far.

Comment: ddox is a major embarrassment imo. It has been up like that for several YEARS. (And when I wrote my own replacement [ see: http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.typecons.nullable.1.html ]), they were like "impossible for one person to do" yet in two weeks, I had a better system than the core team had done in two years, ugh). I would strongly recommend using my doc site http://phobos.dpldocs.info/std.html but if that fails, the one linked above is the more-maintained official site.